# force a promise to reject in karma

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I have the following code which returns the state of a successful or unsuccessful promise:

```
$q.settled = function settled(promise) {

    return $q.when(promise).then(function(value) {
        return { state: 'fulfilled', value: value };
    }, function (reason) {
        return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
    });

}
```

I then test the success methods like so:

```
var result = '',
    promise = {
        success: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };


    $q.settled(promise).then(function(data) {
        result = data;
    });

    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(result.success.state).toBe('fulfilled');
```

Id then expect this to be pretty much the same for the reject, mainly just changing the `.resolve()` to a `.reject()`

```
var result = '',
    promise = {
        failed: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.reject();
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };


    $q.settled(promise).then(function(data) {
        result = data;
    });

    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(result.failed.state).toBe('rejected');
```

but this always returns `fulfilled`. I've tried throwing an error, or passing a string instead of a response but then the tests just return undefined. Any ideas how i can force this example to reject correctly?

Comment: I think even in your code you could use undefined as the first argument to .then(). I think then it should test fine.

Comment: `$q.settled(promise) { ...` ain't a valid method declaration. JS should nag about the `(` there.

Comment: yes sorry @Thomas you are right, i edited the function somewhat to omit pointless stuff that wouldn't help this thing and i've typed it in wrong, good spot

Comment: @gardni have edited the answer below to correct the cited error.

Comment: Should we guess what $q.settled is? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i'm actually using an implementation $q.allSettled found here    https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled
which takes an array of promises and when all are done, lets you know which passed and failed. I tried to omit the bulk of everything to make the test easier to decipher

Comment: Since @82Tuskers answer still contains the same approach: You can't "extract" the value from a Promise! Like `var result; promise.then(data => { result = data }); console.log(result)`. Why? because Time. because [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](/questions/14220321/) because `console.log(result)` will be executed long before the `.then(data => { result = data })`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could modify your code to the following:

SUCCESS

```
var result = '',
    promise = (function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
    })();


promise.then(function(data) {
    result = data;
});

$rootScope.$digest();
expect(result.success.state).toBe('fulfilled');
```

FAILURE

```
var result = '',
    promise = (function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.reject();
        return deferred.promise;
    })();


promise.then(undefined, function(data) {
    result = data;
});

$rootScope.$digest();
expect(result.success.state).toBe('rejected');
```

Please let me know if that works.

Comment: edited the answer as per @Thomas comment above. It is true you cannot call $q.settled(). I think you might be referring to $q.all() ?

Comment: it's a decorator function added to $q

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, `$q.settled(promise){ ...` should throw a Syntax Error. I'd guess you mean

```
$q.settled = function settled(promise){
    return $q.when(promise).then(function(value) {
        return { state: 'fulfilled', value: value };
    }, function (reason) {
        return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
    });
}
```

And the test should look something like this, I'd guess 
*(untested)*

```
describe('Testing $q.settled()', function(){

    it('should be fulfilled', function(done) {
        $q.settled( $q.resolve('success') ).then(function(data){

            expect(data).toEqual({
                state: 'fulfilled',
                value: 'success'
            });

            done();
        });
    });

    it('should should be rejected', function(done) {
        $q.settled( $q.reject('error') ).then(function(data){

            expect(data).toEqual({
                state: 'rejected',
                reason: 'error'
            });

            done();
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: this passes and yet coverage seems to think i never get into the `function (reason) {
        return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
    }); ` even though it returns state of rejected..

Comment: @gardni been a while that I wrote tests in JS. `and yet coverage seems to think i never get into ...` could you explain/elaborate on that. Who exactly says what exactly? *Edit: had an Error in the rejection test, `value: ...` instead of `reason: ...`; fixed it.*

Comment: i use cobertura coverage report, which highlights that the reject method never gets hit, so the test passes i guess because it just creates a reject which returns a state of 'rejected' and a reason of 'error' so looks like it's passing correctly, when actually it's not running the code

Comment: OK. Sry but that's beyond my current knowledge. Would need to build an example and do some tests to wrap my head around that. @gardni

Comment: I'm not sure wether *cobertura* doesn't get that `$q.settled()` can not return a rejected promise. You could try wether it changes something if you change the pattern from `$q.when(promise).then(a, b)` to `$q.when(promise).then(a).catch(b)` but that's just a totally wild guess.